# what is the recommended path for handling and retrying failed transactions?

Tags: transactions

When dealing with failed transactions that can occur to due a program or smart contract error, a connection timeout, simulate transaction failed, or another reason, what is the recommended or possible approach to handle and retry these transactions?

Answer (score 1):

This will depend significantly on the nature of the failure.

For example: after a connection timeout it *may* be appropriate to retry the transaction at a later time depending on the requirements around the timeliness of the information. On the other hand, retrying the same transaction that failed due to a program or smart contract error is unlikely to succeed until the program is updated to fix the error.

It may be helpful to submit examples of the failures you receive as separate questions. Having more details about the specific nature of the failure could help others generate possible approaches to handling and retrying.